# Como organizar um array de uma lista

Tags: php, array

Um array que está assim:

```
Array
    (
        [nome_e_sobrenome] => Array
            (
                [0] => Luiz Felipe Machado
                [1] => Maria Rita de Cássia
            )

        [usuario] => Array
            (
                [0] => luizf
                [1] => mariar
            )

        [senha] => Array
            (
                [0] => XXXX
                [1] => YYYY
            )

    )
```

Ficar assim:

```
  Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [nome_e_sobrenome] => Luiz Felipe Machado
                [usuario] => luizf
                [senha] => XXX
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [nome_e_sobrenome] => Maria Rita de Cássia
                [usuario] => mariar
                [senha] => YYY
            )
    )
```

Comment: Já tentou alguma coisa? algum código, qq coisa?!

Comment: Ainda estou tentando...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Partindo do príncipio que sabemos as chaves de ante-mão:

```
$original = array(
    'nome_e_sobrenome' => array(
        'Luiz Felipe Machado',
        'Maria Rita de Cássia'  
    ),
    'usuario' => array(
        'luizf',
        'mariar'
    ),
    'senha' => array(
        'XXX',
        'YYYY'
    ),
);

$new = array();
foreach($original['nome_e_sobrenome'] as $pos => $val) {
    $new[] = array(
        'nome_e_sobrenome' => $original['nome_e_sobrenome'][$pos],
        'usuario' => $original['usuario'][$pos],
        'senha' => $original['senha'][$pos],
    );
}
```

O novo formato vai agora estar em `$new`:

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://ideone.com/KDeviq)

Para o caso de não saberes as chaves de ante-mão:

```
$original = array(
    'nome_e_sobrenome' => array(
        'Luiz Felipe Machado',
        'Maria Rita de Cássia'  
    ),
    'usuario' => array(
        'luizf',
        'mariar',
    ),
    'senha' => array(
        'XXX',
        'YYYY'
    ),
);

$new = array();
foreach($original as $key => $val) {
    foreach($val as $idx => $dado) {
        $new[$idx][$key] = $dado;
    }
}
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://ideone.com/XHMIw4)

Comment: Nossa, estava bolando uma resposta igual a sua :)

Comment: hehehe @jlHertel :P

Comment: Não é só isso, os valores e chaves serão dinâmicos.

Comment: @IvanFerrer, editei para essa possibilidade também, é o segundo exemplo

Comment: O segundo exemplo funcionou perfeito, valeu!