# Como eu poderia mesclar os laços abaixo?

Tags: php, phpexcel

Esta é a planilha:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este é o código:

```
public function loadExcel($file, $dir)
{
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
    $filterValidation = new Application_Model_Filter_FilterValidation();
    if (file_exists($dir . DS . $file)) {
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($dir . DS . $file);
        $arrayData = array();
        //laço 1
        foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
            $arrayData[$worksheet->getTitle()] = $worksheet->toArray(null, true, true, true);
        }

        $sheetData = array_values($arrayData)[0];
        $header = $sheetData[1];
        unset($sheetData[1]);
        $data = array_values($sheetData);
        //return $data;
        if(count($data)) {
            $result = array();
            //laço 2
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                if (count($value)) {
                    //laço 3
                    foreach ($value as $letter => $val) {
                        if ($header[$letter] != '' && !is_null($header[$letter]) && !is_numeric($header[$letter])) {
                            if (!is_null($val)) {
                                $result[$header[$letter]][] = $val;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            $new = array();
            //laço 4
            foreach ($result as $key => $val) {
                if (count($val)) {
                    //laço 5
                    foreach ($val as $idx => $dado) {
                        if (count($dado)) {
                            $new[$idx][$key] = $dado;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return $new;
        }
    }
}
```

Resultado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [NOME] => Luiz Felipe Machado
            [USUARIO] => alunoguten001
            [SENHA] => aluno001
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [NOME] => Maria Rita de Cássia
            [USUARIO] => alunoguten002
            [SENHA] => aluno002
        )

)
```

**PS:** parte desta solução foi resolvida [**nesta pergunta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/186562/como-organizar-um-array-de-uma-lista), porém não creio que seja necessário fazer três **foreach** para tratar o dado, acredito que dá pra melhorar isso em um único laço, só não sei como poderia melhorar?

Comment: Você poderia trocar esses laços foreach por laços for, assim o consumo de memória seria melhor, infelizmente muita coisa não pode ser feita, já que php tem poucos recursos e é péssimo no quesito código limpo e otimização.

Comment: Não conheço muito da biblitoeca PHPExcel. Poderia postar a saída do comando var_dump($data) antes do comando if(count($data)) ?

Comment: o que exatamente o código faz para gerar este resultado?

Answer (score 0):

Vou te dar uma sugestão, salve esta planilha em CSV e utilize o seguinte código.

```
function loadFile ( $file ) 
{
    $data = [];
    if ( ( $handle = fopen( $file, "r" ) ) !== FALSE) {
        $i = 0;
        while ( ( $data = fgetcsv( $handle, 1000, ";" ) ) !== FALSE ) {

            if ( $i == 0 ) {
                $i++;
                continue;
            }

            $data[] = [
                'nome'    => utf8_encode( $data[0] ),
                'usuario' => utf8_encode( $data[1] ),
                'senha'   => utf8_encode( $data[2] )
            ];

            $i++;
        }
    }

    return $data;
}
```

P.S: Isso só vai ser útil para você somente com arquivos do tipo CSV.

Comment: Pois é, não é útil para mim.